# Instantiate a template class <erroneous-expression>?

Tags: c++, templates

Here is my code :

```
template<typename T, template<typename = T,typename =std::allocator<typename = T> > class Container= std::vector>
 class stack
 {
     public:
     Container<T> cont;
     stack()
     {

     }
 };
```

If i replace the very first line of code to below code then it works :

```
template<typename T, template<typename elem= T,typename =std::allocator<elem> > class Container= std::vector>
```

but i want to ask that i've read when you don't use templates type parameter then you can write this : `<typename=default_type>` or `<typename>` . Also `T` in above code is visible in parameter list of template template parameter `Container` ( i.e type parameter `T` is visible in it's whole parameterization clause  ). so  all in all i think so it should work.
but it doesn't and gives the error :

```
error: expression '<erroneous-expression> = <erroneous-expression>' is not a constant-expression
error: template argument 1 and 2 are invalid
```

So can anyone explain why i am seeing these errors, what is erroneous-expression?

Comment: "erroneous-expression" is probably just your compiler being confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a template parameter is itself a template, then its own template parameters are not used or relevant in the context of the outer template other than to define the "template signature" of the template-template parameter. Therefore, you don't need neither parameter names, as they are not usable or necessary. You can simply say this:

```
template <typename T, template<typename, typename> class Container = std::vector>
class stack
{
  typedef Container<T, std::allocator<T> > CT;
  // ...
};
```

Here `template <typename, typename>` is just the template signature of the `Container` template class that you expect.

In C++11 you can do better and allow more general containers by using variadic templates:

```
template <typename T, template<typename...> class Container = std::vector> class stack;
```

---

[For completeness:] Putting default types in the template parameter's parameter list also works, and it means you can omit those types later (as you already do):

```
template<typename = T, typename = std::allocator<T> > class Container

---> now we can say:

Container<T> x;  // use second default argument
Container<> y;   // use both default arguments
```

---

To answer your question: You want to specify a default **type** in

```
 template <typename = T, typename = std::allocator<typename> > class Container
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                            Error!!
```

but `std::allocator<typename>` isn't a type -- it's not even legal syntax. You could either have a template parameter which once again is a template, i.e. `template <typename> = std::allocator`, but that wouldn't be matched by `std::vector`, or you have an actual type:

```
template <typename = T, typename = std::allocator<T> > class Container
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                   OK, this is a type
```

Comment: Still you also didn't answer why my code (very first line of very first code block) is not working?

Comment: The second nested default type `typename =std::allocator<typename = T>` doesn't work, because that's not a type, but a template. What you should say is `typename =std::allocator<T>`, because that's a type.

Comment: Thanks Kerrek for nice and **explaining** answer) , Btw consider your answer for editing since my line was **std::allocator<typename = T>**

Comment: No problem. I just fixed an error, though: You *can* indeed have default types for the parameters of the template parameters, as you do in your code; the default types aren't useless as I originally claimed. Indeed, when you say `Container<T>`, you're relying on that default type in `Container`.

Answer (score 0):

In the parameter-list of a class template, when you specify *template template parameter* , then template parameter of the *template template parameter* is not used (in fact, they *cannot* be used). As such, you can skip mentioning even their names.

So what you should be doing is this:

```
template<typename T, template<class,class> class Container= std::vector>
class stack
{
     Container<T, std::allocator<T> > cont;
};
```

That is, all that is required for the *template template parameter* is the number of parameter(s), and the information what their parameter(s) : type or value.

You can also write this for better readability:

```
template<typename T, template<class U,class Allocator> class Container= std::vector>
class stack
{
     Container<T, std::allocator<T> > cont;
};
```

---

As for why your first code is not working, because of `std::allocator<typename = T>` which should be simply `std::allocator<T>`. That is, this should work:

```
template<typename T, template<typename =T,typename =std::allocator<T> >  class Container= std::vector>
```

See it here : http://ideone.com/eO8qT

But then such *default types* of the template template parameter is not even considered. They're ignored.

Now you might ask why `std::allocator<typename =T>` doesn't work. Because its ill-formed. Do you think `std::vector<typename =T>` makes any sense?  Please note that `std::allocator` and `std::vector` both are class template, but `Container` is not a class template. Its a *template template parameter* of a class template. That is why, `typename =T` is allowed for this, while its not allowed for class templates such as `std::allocator`.

Comment: Still you didn't answer why my code (very first line of very first code block) is not working?

Comment: did you mean "then template parameter **of** the template template parameter is not used (in fact, they cannot be used)" ?

Comment: @Mr. Anubis: Now I explained that. You should write simpy `std::allocator<T>`, NOT `std::allocator<typename = T>`.

Comment: you're are always telling me what line has problem and removes the error. not a single time you told me why i shouldn't do such thing and why this is happening :( , Looks like many of here are for points not to help :(

Comment: @Mr. Anubis:  I thought that was enough. But then I realized that was not enough for you.. Anyway, I added an explanation to it.